# setState return NULL in React and Node Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api, axios

I have a Node Js API where I get my database data with a `find` function. It works perfectly and send my results. 
Using React and Axios, I get the data but as soon as I pass the data into `setState` it sends `null`.

Here is my API `find()` function

```
dbo.collection("students").find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var students = result;
        reponse.send(students);
        db.close();
    });
```

And here is my Axios `constructor()` and `componentDidMont()`

```
    constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      students: [],
    }
  }

    componentDidMount() {
    axios.get("http://localhost:3333/").then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      this.setState({students:data.data.students});
      console.log(this.state);
    });
  }
```

`console.log(data)` return this

```
`Object { data: (33) […], status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest }`
```

While `console.log(this.state)` return this

`Object { students: undefined }`

Comment: Are you sure there is a `students` in your `data.data`?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly state updates are async so you wouldn't see the updated state immediately

Secondly, the response data has data which is an array, so you just need to set the state with `data.data`

```
this.setState({students:data.data});
```